# Get the first selected value from dropdown with jQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I would like to change prices by the selected options. Actually I use this jQuery-Code.

```
item.find('select').on('change', function () {
  price_updater($(this));
});
```

The select dropdown looks like

```
<select name="products_qty" size="1" class="SumoUnder" tabindex="-1">
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="250">250</option>
  <option value="500">500</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
</select>
```

The jQuery Code only works when I change the dropdown field. How do I get the first value?

Comment: Add `.trigger('change')` to the end of your current jQuery

Comment: Sorry for this double posting but your solution works fine.

Comment: No problems, glad it solved the issue for you